# Rails5、DEVISEのパスワード再発行(パスワードリセット)でActionController::UnknownFormat エラーが発生しました。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

・エラー文
ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:

・該当ファイル
**app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb**

```
<p>こんにちは、<%= @resource.email %>様</p>

<p>以下リンクよりパスワードを変更してください。</p>

<p><%= link_to 'パスワードの変更はこちら', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>
```

メールは送信されますが、ブラウザでは上記エラー文が表示される状態です。
上記ファイル内のコードが間違っていますでしょうか？
DEVISEのコントローラーはオーバーライドしております。
アドバイス頂けましたら幸いです。宜しくお願い致します。

※ 追記箇所
**app/controllers/users/passwords_controller.rb**
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
end

Comment: deviseの対象はUserモデルでしょうか？

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます！対象はUserモデルになります。

Comment: となると、ディレクトリの名前がおかしい気がします。`rails generate devise:views users`でviewを展開しましたか？

Comment: rails generate devise:views users を実行しましたのでusersディレクトリはあります。ユーザーのマイページなどで使用しております。ただご指摘通りディレクトリの名前はおかしいかと思います。

Comment: usersディレクトリがあるなら、deviseが参照するファイルは`app/views/users/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb`になると思います。その上で、`config/initializers/devise.rb`の`config.scoped_views = true"`していますか？

Comment: オーバーライドした`app/controllers/users/passwords_controller.rb`の記述に間違いがあると思います。

Comment: config/initial‌​izers/devise.rbのconf‌​ig.scoped_views = true"していますか？
> ファイル確認しましたが、trueにしておりました。

Comment: オーバーライドしたapp/controllers/users/passwords_controller.rbの記述に間違‌​いがあると思います。
> 上記に追記しました。継承はしていますが、特に記述はしていないので、何か足りない可能性はありますでしょうか？

Comment: コメント欄でディスカッションしないでください。追加情報は質問を編集して追記してください。